# Importing swing package in module-info

Tags: java, swing, java-11, java-module

I'm trying to use swing API in a simple java project where need to import javax.swing package in module-info.java

I'm using openJDK-11 on eclipse IDE

```
module ml.garba.testeur {
    requires javax.swing; 
}
```

This is JFrame instance

```
package ml.garba.testeur.vue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Fenetre_Testeur extends JFrame {

}
```

It seems the importing of swing package does not work.

I need help

Comment: The declaration `requires javax.swing;` shouldn't have worked either ideally.

Answer (score 5):

A module-info declaration has to declare required *modules*, not packages.

Therefore, your declaration has to be

```
requires java.desktop;
```

See [the API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/index.html) for the existing modules and contained (exported) packages.

Comment: I've fix this when I changed javax.swing to java.desktop

Comment: Nice answer. Would it make more sense if the first sentence read "has to declare *modules* and not *packages* that it `requires`"? Or maybe, I am the only one reading it multiple times and questioning: "could this be improved to convey the message clearly?"

Comment: @Naman I’m not sure whether your suggested alternative is easier to read. But I’m still open to suggestions.

Comment: What's the definitive way of finding out which module I need to require for a given fully qualified class name?

Comment: @NikoO how do you find out about the qualified class name in the first place?

Comment: @Holger e.g. from an example code. Or Eclipse will just suggest it. If I type `JOptionPane` and hit enter, Eclipse automatically adds `import javax.swing.JOptionPane;` even though the necessary line in module-info.java is not there yet.

Comment: @NikoO I just tried it and the first thing, Eclipse suggested afterwards, was adding the `requires java.desktop;` to the `module-info`. Regardless of what you use to get the qualified name, getting the module name should not be different. Most example code on Stackoverflow doesn’t contain `import` statements, so you have to use either, the IDE’s auto-completion, which should provide module names as well, or look up the documentation, which also provides the module name.

Comment: Not bad, Eclipse does indeed suggest the appropriate `requires` It's buried in the middle of a bunch of other options so I didn't see it.
Maybe not on StackOverflow, but first google result for `Java MessageBox` had the import but not the module. Or maybe you want to copy a line from another project and you don't know which `requires` it is. Use your imagination ;)
"Look up the documentation" is the crux here. The official documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html does not mention java.desktop, so how would I know which module I need to add?

Comment: @NikoO you’ve linked to the Java 7 documentation, but modules were introduced in Java 9. Use the documentation matching your Java version or use the latest but care for “since” notes. Check [`JOptionPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html); the module is named right at the top.

Answer (score -2):

So, I think that your issue may be in your import statement.

Since you've only imported

`javax.swing.JFrame;`

You might not be able to have your code run. However, if you try

`import javax.swing.*;`

It should hopefully work.